# Can anyone edify me on where my logic is faulty in either/both of the following mysql statements?

Tags: sql, mysql

I wish to update the principal_staff_ID column in the staff_used table with the principal_staff_ID in the jobs table. These two tables are related via a common job_ID.

First attempt:

```
update staff_used su 
set su.principal_staff_ID = (select j.principal_staff_ID
                               from job j where j.job_ID = su.job_ID);
```

Second attempt:

```
update staff_used su
join job j on j.job_ID = su.job_ID
set su.principal_staff_ID = j.principal_staff_ID;
```

Comment: What were the troubles you ran into?  It always helps to explain where you ran into problems, possibly with an exact error message (if that's what happened) or with an explanation of the undesirable side-effects of a statement that appeared to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the first query, you must have a row in the Job table for every row in the Staff_Used table - or the DBMS will set the Staff_Used.Principal_Staff_ID value to NULL for every unmatched row.  To make that form of UPDATE safe, you have to write:

```
UPDATE staff_used su 
   SET su.principal_staff_ID =  (SELECT j.principal_staff_ID
                                   FROM job j 
                                  WHERE j.job_ID = su.job_ID)
 WHERE su.principle_staff_ID IN (SELECT j.principal_staff_ID
                                   FROM job j 
                                  WHERE j.job_ID = su.job_ID);
```

The second sub-query ensures that only rows in Staff_Used with a matching row in Job are updated.  It's also a good reason to prefer the join notation!

Answer (score 1):

The second form should work. You could try this form:

```
update staff_used
set su.principal_staff_ID = j.principal_staff_ID    
from staff_used su 
inner join ww_job j on j.job_ID = su.job_ID
```

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thank you both. The second form did work (eventually), but I had to delete an unset field under j.job_ID. The error query browser returned was "principal_staff_ID cannot be null", however the cause of the problem seemed to be a j.job_ID that was not set. I now have an example of updating with a join that will help me understand - thanks. I hope in due course to get a better feel for why the sub-query didn't work as that seems more logical in some ways.

Comment: @SaminOz: if Mitch's answer helped you, his answer deserves an up-vote from you.  You're allowed to up-vote more than one answer if there are several helpful ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the second attempt isn't working, try this: (unsure if MySQL supports this syntax?)

```
update su
set su.principal_staff_ID = j.principal_staff_ID
from staff_used as su
inner join job j on j.job_ID = su.job_ID
```